# component get refreshed after file saved in the assest folder in Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating pdf file on the **server** side, the file is saved in the assets folder on the **client** side . The problem is that after that the pdf file got saved it's refresh the component with link to download that file , and it's make the link broken...
I realized that if I run the projects with the command ***ng serve --live-reload=false***, it's work perfectly.
But I wonder if there is way to exclude the assets folder or other folders inside there from being rendering.

Comment: Are you talking about published app or development?

Comment: If you have a traditional web browser (client) and web server (server) architecture then the asset folder is maintained *server* side, not client side. So if you create a pdf and place it in the asset folder it is still located on the server. The browser does not have access to folders on the client PC. You can return a PDF in a web request that is saved on the client PC but the document will be saved to the download folder (or whatever folder is selected by default) or they have to select a place to save it if doing a save as.

Comment: This is only an issue during development correct? There is no assets folder on ‘the client’ as the client is the browser.

Comment: Your approach will NOT work at all after app will be deployed ;)

Comment: So if I understand you right , I need to save the pdf file on the server, and make the link path to the server  ? @Igor